# how to change the bootstrap multidate property dynamically

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker as follows,

```
$('#ColumnValue').datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
            autoclose: false,
            multidate: true
            }).on('changeDate', function () {                
            });
```

Depending on some condition i want to set multidate property to false.

I have tried following code without success

```
 $("#data").on("change", function () {
    $('#ColumnValue').datepicker({
                        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                        autoclose: true,
                        multidate: false
                    });
 });
```

what is proper way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

well figured it out

```
  $("#data").on("change", function () {
     $('#ColumnValue').datepicker('remove');       
     $('#ColumnValue').datepicker({
                                format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                                autoclose: true,
                                multidate: false
                            });
         });
```